# Maven - Never Update Snapshots by GroupID

Tags: maven

How can I prevent Maven from ever updating a SNAPSHOT dependency from a particular group?

I'm stuck depending on a library that insists on daily updates to 1.0-SNAPSHOT, but only makes releases every few months. I need changes from a daily SNAPSHOT build that was made recently, but I'm getting fed up with the developers of this framework introducing breaking changes. Hence, I'd like to tell Maven to never update anything from this groupId unless I specifically say so.

Any ideas? The only other approach I can think of is to fork the repo, edit the POM to a version number all of my own, and then depend on that.

Answer (score 2):

Using snapshots this can always happen. But you could install the version you need with a specific version number in your local repository and then use your version. Something like:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>my.group</groupId>
   <artifactId>my.artifact</artifactId>
   <version>1.2-TEMPVERSION</version>
</dependency>
```

It's a workaround and should not go in Production like this.

Comment: Thanks - sadly I've no alternative until the people making the dependency start doing proper versioning!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use maven 3, you can use a timestamed snapshot, i.e. replace the dependency with its timestamped version. Something like:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>my.group</groupId>
   <artifactId>my.artifact</artifactId>
   <version>1.2-20140401.124312.1</version>
</dependency>
```

You can also convert a SNAPSHOT dependency automatically to its corresponding timestamped version ("locking a version") using the [versions-maven-plugin][1]:

```
mvn versions:lock-snapshots -Dincludes=my.group:my.artifact:jar::1.2-SNAPSHOT
```

Of course, if your repository manager throws out old SNAPSHOTS after a while, this might cease to work when the needed SNAPSHOT is no longer in your local repository.

Answer (score 0):

I think setting the update policy to `never` for snapshots solves the issue; see [here](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.3/maven-settings/settings.html)

like

```xml
    <repository>
        <id>my_id</id>
        <name>my_name</name>
        <releases>[...]</releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
        </snapshots>
        <url>http://the-repository.org/repositories/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
```

Haven't (successfuly) tried yet. But I went into the same problem and that's my attempt to handle it.